# Demandware external CSS file

Tags: css, styles, demandware

I have very little demandaware knowledge as my boss who was supposed to train me this year ended up quitting so now I am in the dark. I am attending workshops later this year but until then Google and stackover is my teacher. I am editing a content asset and at the top of the code there is a link to an external CSS sheet. All of the work I have done in the content asset pages, the CSS and html have all been on one page and I have no idea how to get to that external CSS sheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is what the link looks like

```
<link href="test/fitting/css/test-fitting.css?$staticlink$" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is referencing a file in the content library. You can browse those files by going to the Import/Export module within the Content section of Business Manager. Within the Import/Export Mosule is a link to manage content images. Click that. This should open a window that allows you to browse, upload, and delete the files. You can simply upload a file with the same name in the same location to replace the existing file.

Comment: Is there a way I can download that file? When I click the link the screen just dims and a loading bar just loads forever.

Comment: I usually download it by viewing the source of the content asset preview and copying the link that is generated and opening it in a new tab. But you can also access the folder directly via a WebDAV client like Cyberduck or BitKinex.